# Eliminating Octave starting text

Tags: octave

When Octave starts up, it prints out

> GNU Octave, version 4.2.1 Copyright (C) 2017 John W. Eaton and others.
>   This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
>   There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.
>
> Octave was configured for "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
>
> Additional information about Octave is available at
>   http://www.octave.org.
>
> Please contribute if you find this software useful. For more
>   information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html
>
> Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug
>   reports. For information about changes from previous versions, type
>   'news'.

Is there a way to turn off this printout? I don't need to read it every time I start Octave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the quiet option, like so:

```
$ octave --quiet
octave-4.3.0+>
```

From the [command line options section](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Options.html) in the manual:

> --silent
>   --quiet
>   -q
>
> ```
> Don’t print the usual greeting and version message at startup.
> ```